# creating and using java web service to connect remote mysql server

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

In my android application, I want to create and use java web service to connect to remote mysql server. I tried searching for the same but results are vague.

Can anyone please suggest me how can I do following things:

- Create a java web service which connects to remote mysql server (without using jdbc)
- Publish that service
- Use that service to send & receive data in json format

Is all of the above are possible?

Any article/link/code snippet welcomed.

### Edit

So sample web service would be something like this??

**HelloWeb.java**

```
@WebService
public class HelloWeb {

    @WebMethod
    public String sayGreeting(String name) {

        return "Greeting " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9898/HelloWeb", new HelloWeb());
        System.out.println("HelloWeb service is ready");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case android phone is client, which request data to `Java Web Service` on one server. And that `Web Service` will try connect with `MySql` with is running on separate server/PC. Right ?? Or I am understanding it wrong ??

Comment: Absolutely correct mate !

Comment: In that case you will need JDBC driver on server where Web Service is is hosted. Then you can follow steps in mentioned in @duffymo's answer

Comment: so according to you and *Maroun Baydoun* , JDBC is must in order to connect to mysql server??

Comment: Yes...But is there any specific reason you don't wan't to use JDBC driver ??

Comment: Not really. Actually I'm new to this JDBC things and my boss told me not to use it. Poor me :(

Comment: It's easy....You can get many tutorials online....

Comment: jdbc code is something like this na: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, username,
     password);` ??

Comment: Your boss should not be dictating how to connect to a relational database.  JDBC is how it's done in Java.  Every vendor gives you their driver classes to make sure that it's done properly.  Why on earth would a sane person recommend that you reinvent all of that for yourself?  Your boss should be fired.

Comment: Yup....More example on http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/ and http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

Comment: @hemu : Can you please check edited code and just let me know if I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like all computer science problems, I'd decompose this one into smaller, more manageable pieces:

1. Create an interface-based service that fulfills your use case.
2. Expose the interface-based service as a web service, SOAP or REST, to interact with clients via
   HTTP
3. Parse, validate, and bind the JSON.
4. Create an interface-based DAO that uses JDBC to connect to MySQL and perform CRUD operations on the client's behalf.
5. Inject the DAO into the web service and let it interact with MySQL using JDBC.

You can test each piece independently this way.  I think it'll be more reusable, too.

Comment: Can you please check edited code and just let me know if I'm on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

You need JDBC to connect to MySQL. You can abstract that by using an ORM, but it would still be using JDBC on a lower level.

You can create a REST web service using JAX-RS [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html)

Comment: Can you please check edited code and just let me know if I'm on the right track?